# get data from multiple JSONs to database

Tags: python, json, postgresql

im new in python and i'm working on a project that i need to retrieve data from different JSONs and store it in a database (im using Postgresql). The JSONs url are all from the same website: https://www.ine.pt/xportal/xmain?xpid=INE&xpgid=ine_main

But they have different codes when it comes to select for example a year or a location.

This is an example of one JSON: https://www.ine.pt/ine/json_indicador/pindica.jsp?op=2&varcd=0010042&Dim1=S3A202006&Dim2=1701106&Dim3=T&lang=PT

every "Dim" in this url can have different codes. I need a way in python to get for instance 18 different cities to get all the data i need without doing it one by one.

This is an example of the JSON data:

```
[ {
  "IndicadorCod" : "0010042",
  "IndicadorDsg" : "Valor mediano de avaliação bancária (€/ m²) por Localização geográfica (Município - 2013) e Tipo de construção; Mensal - INE, Inquérito à avaliação bancária na habitação",
  "MetaInfUrl" : "https://www.ine.pt/bddXplorer/htdocs/minfo.jsp?var_cd=0010042&lingua=PT",
  "DataExtracao" : "2020-06-29T15:55:51.640+01:00",
  "DataUltimoAtualizacao" : "2020-06-29",
  "UltimoPref" : "Maio de 2020",
  "Dados" : {
    "202005" : [ {
      "geocod" : "1701106",
      "geodsg" : "Lisboa",
      "dim_3" : "T",
      "dim_3_t" : "Total",
      "valor" : "3084"
    } ]
  }
} ]
```

Besides that i have another question. There is a field in this JSON which is the year and the month of the data. That field is the one below "Dados" and in this example it is "202005". How can i get this field since this is a label instead of a "value"? Basically i want to store the year, location and the field "valor" on a database.

Thank you for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

For parsing JSON data in Python, you can use json library. What it does is, basically imports all JSON data to a Python dictionary(which is a data type similar to hash maps). After that you have to write parse functions for each JSON type.

For Example for you JSON:

```
import json

data = json.dump("JSON_file_path") # If you have a JSON file
data = json.dumps(json_data) # If you have JSON data as String
id = data["IndicadorCod"] # How you get data from dictionary using keys
```

Comment: nice! but i need to do that for multiple jsons with different codes in the url, they will have the same fields, only diferent data when i change a "dim" code

Comment: Well, that totally depends on your use case. There is no "function call" for such tasks. You should implement your own logic.

Comment: im new in python but i was thinking of using some sort of cycle to iterate the url throught the different codes i have but i cant seem to find a way to do that

Comment: ------------------up-------------------